# Scrapy - ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: #mw-head

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm getting the following traceback but unsure how to refactor.

```
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: #mw-head
```

Full code:

```
class MissleSpiderBio(scrapy.Spider): 

    name = 'missle_spider_bio'
    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/...']
```

this is the part giving me issues (I believe)

```
    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split('/')[-1]
        table = response.xpath('///div/table[2]/tbody')
        rows = table.xpath('//tr')
        row = rows[2]
        row.xpath('td//text()')[0].extract()
        wdata = {}
        for row in response.xpath('//* \
        [@class="wikitable"]//tbody//tr'):
            for link in response.xpath('//a/@href'):
                link = link.extract()
                if((link.strip() != '')):
                    yield Request(link, callback=self.parse)
                    #wdata.append(link)
                else:
                    yield None
                #wdata = {}
                #wdata['link'] = BASE_URL + 
                #row.xpath('a/@href').extract() #[0]
                wdata['link'] = BASE_URL + link 
                request = scrapy.Request(wdata['link'],\
                callback=self.get_mini_bio, dont_filter=True) 
                request.meta['item'] = MissleItem(**wdata)
                yield request
```

here is the second part of the code:

```
    def get_mini_bio(self, response):
        BASE_URL_ESCAPED = 'http:\/\/en.wikipedia.org'
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['image_urls'] = [] 
        img_src = response.xpath('//table[contains(@class, \ 
        "infobox")]//img/@src')
        if img_src:
            item['image_urls'] = ['http:' + img_src[0].extract()]
        mini_bio = ''
        paras = response.xpath('//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/p[text()\ 
        or  normalize-space(.)=""]').extract()
        for p in paras:
            if p =='<p></p>':
                break
            mini_bio += p

        mini_bio = mini_bio.replace('href="/wiki', 'href="' + \ 
        BASE_URL + '/wiki')
        mini_bio = mini_bio.replace('href="#', item['link'] + '#')
        item['mini_bio'] = mini_bio
        yield item
```

I tried refactoring but am now getting a:

```
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: #mw-head
```

any help would be immensely appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you were on the right track with the commented out [0].

```
xpath().extract() #returns a list of strings
```

You need to select the string with [0]

Answer (score 0):

```
row.xpath('a/@href').extract()
```

That expression evaluates to a list NOT a string. When you pass the URL to the request object, scrapy expects a string, not a list

To fix this, you have a few options:
You can use LinkExtractors which will allow you to search a page for links and automatically create scrapy request objects for those links:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html

OR
You could run a for loop and go through each of the links:

from scrapy.spiders import Request

```
for link in response.xpath('//a/@href'):
    link = link.extract()
    if((link.strip() != '')):
        yield Request(link, callback=self.parse)
    else:
        yield None
```

You can add whatever string filters you want to that code

OR

If you just want the first link, you can use `.extract_first()` instead of `.extract()`

Comment: thanks for responding. I tried incorporating your for loop but now i'm getting a different traceback. ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: #mw-head. i made the edits to my original post. perhaps i didn't incorporate your recommendation  in correctly?

Comment: Ah! What's happening there is that not all `<a>` tags contain URLs, some of them contain something called anchors, which tell the browser to go to a URL and then scroll down to a certain section:

https://smallbiztrends.com/2013/06/what-is-the-anchor-tag.html

So basically the `<a>` link you're targeting is not a URL, but an anchor

Comment: There may be other ways to fix it, but one simple way is to do a string search on the first non-whitespace character to see if it is a '#' character.
If it is that character, then you can ignore the link and `yield None`