# Scrapy - Struggling with retrieving text

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to build a scraper with Scrapy and i'm struggling with returning the desired text. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Request
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse  
import re
from urllib import *


BASE_URL = 'http://murderpedia.org/'
PROTOCOL = 'https:'
```

Here is my Item Class

```
class CornFlakeItem(scrapy.Item):

    name = scrapy.Field()
    bio = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    bio_image = scrapy.Field()
    image_paths = scrapy.Field()  

    classification = scrapy.Field()
    characteristics = scrapy.Field()
    number_of_victims = scrapy.Field()
    date_of_murders = scrapy.Field()
    date_of_birth = scrapy.Field()
    victims_profile = scrapy.Field()
    method_of_murder = scrapy.Field()
    location = scrapy.Field()
    status = scrapy.Field()
```

Here is my Bio Class:

```
class CornFlakeBio(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'corn-flake-killers'
    start_urls = ['http://murderpedia.org/male.A/index.A.htm']
```

Here is my Parse Function:

```
    def parse(self, response):

        table= 
        response.xpath('//td[contains(font//font/text(),
        "Victims")]/../..')
        urls = table.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
        for url in urls:
            if (url.startswith('mailto:')): 
                yield None
            else:
                yield Request(response.urljoin(url), self.parse_person)
```

Here is my parse person function:

```
    def parse_person(self, response):

        table = response.xpath('//*[@id="table4"]')
        for row in table.xpath('//tbody'):


            text = {
             'Classification' : 
             row.xpath('//tr[3]/td/style/text()').extract_first(),
             'Characteristics': 
             row.xpath('//tr[4]/td/style/text()').extract_first(),
             'Number of Victims' : 
             row.xpath('//tr[5]/td/style/text()').extract_first(),
            'Date of Murders': 
             row.xpath('//tr[6]/td/style/text()').extract_first(),
            'Date of Birth': 
             row.xpath('//tr[7]/td/style/text()').extract_first(), 
            'Victims Profile': 
             row.xpath('//tr[8]/td/style/text()').extract_first(), 
            'Method of Murder': 
             row.xpath('//tr[9]/td/style/text()').extract_first(),  
            'Location' : 
            row.xpath('//tr[10]/td/style/text()').extract_first(),
            'Status' : 
            row.xpath('//tr[11]/td/style/text()').extract_first()}

            text = ''.join(text) 

            print(text)[:10]
```

I have a feeling my problem lies in the xpath for each individual row but perhaps not ? ...

Any help here would be immensely appreciated.

Here are highlights from my updated log file:

Comment: What error/output are you getting?

Comment: @AlphaTested thanks for responding. i added the log files up above

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're getting this error because one (or more) of your URLs inside of the `<a href="some URL">` is actually something **other** **than** a link to a web page. So in this case it looks like it could be a link to send an email to a specific email address

You can either use Link Extractors from scrapy:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html

OR

You can do some string filtering in Python to watch out for things like anchor tags (start with `#` ) or email addresses (often start with `mailto`)

This answer I gave a short while back may give some additional context for optional reading:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52900592/9693088

Comment: i made the changes you recommended in my original code. I'm no longer receiving the 'mailto' errors, in fact i'm not longer receiving any errors, I just dont see any text being generated. do you or anyone else have any idea what i'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure, a good step to take would be to use the scrapy shell to try to debug further: 
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html